# Socket.io is closed before the connection is established

Tags: node.js, angular, mongoose, socket.io

I use in my app mongoose.js and socket.io. I try to emit an event in a mongoose callback. But my client (angular) does not seem to receive anything. Besides, it is continuously disconnected every time an event is emitted server side, in the callback and with 'user' data.

To be precise, my User model is wrapped in the following manner :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

class DBReader {

    constructor(name, schema) {
        this.Model = require(`./models/${name}`)
    }

    find(params, callback) {
        this.Model.find(params, callback)
    }

    findOne(params, callback) {
        this.Model.findOne(params, callback)
    }

    findById(id, callback) {
        this.Model.findById(id, callback)
    }
}

module.exports = DBReader
```

And I instantiate my user like this :

```
const User = new DBReader('user')
```

The following code works, that is to say my client is not disconnected and receives the two events (It works because I don't emit 'user' data in the callback)...

```
function socket(httpServer) {

  const io = require('socket.io')(httpServer)

  io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log('User connected')

    socket.emit('hello', 'Hello World !')

    User.findOne({}, (err, user) => {
      console.log(err)
      console.log(user) // Displays the requested user
    })

    socket.emit('hello', 'Wooorld !')

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      console.log('User disconnected')
    })
  })
}
```

This code works too (because I don't emit 'user' data).

```
function socket(httpServer) {

  const io = socketio(httpServer)

  io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log('User connected')

    socket.emit('hello', 'Hello World !')

    User.findOne({}, (err, user) => {
      console.log(err)
      console.log(user)
      socket.emit('hello', 'hellooo !')
    })

    socket.emit('hello', 'Wooorld !')

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      console.log('User disconnected')
    })
  })
}
```

But this code does not work (event emitted in the callback with 'user' data)...

```
function socket(httpServer) {

  const io = socketio(httpServer)

  io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log('User connected')

    socket.emit('hello', 'Hello World !')

    User.findOne({}, (err, user) => {
      console.log(err)
      console.log(user)
      socket.emit('hello', user)
    })

    socket.emit('hello', 'Wooorld !')

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      console.log('User disconnected')
    })
  })
}
```

Do you have any explanation ? Do you need further information ?

Comment: which module for socket.io  are you using in your angular ?

Comment: socket.io-client

Comment: I'm wondering right now if my issue could come from the object type I try to send. I thought socket.io was doing all the job, but what if my user is not a valid JSON string ?

Comment: Yes i guess you have a problem with your user object ! did you get your object correctly with console.log(user) before your emit ?

Comment: If the client gets disconnected I would assume that the server is throwing an error.

Comment: Yep, I can display my user info. But I tried to copy it in a JSONLinter and I get few errors. Is there any workaround ?

Comment: try to send it like an object like this : socket.emit('hello', {myUser:user})

Comment: Already tried it and it does not work. I currently try to convert my user object into plain javascript with mongoose lean method.

Comment: I can't reproduce, to be honest: Mongoose results passed to Socket.IO `emit` work just fine. You could try and see if using `socket.emit('hello', user.toJSON())` works better.

Comment: user.toJSON() = undefined ; I used JSON.stringify(user) which produces a string (of course it does, but I checked it to be sure ^^). And I still get an error.

Comment: If you're using `lean`, `user.toJSON` would be undefined, otherwise is should exist. If not, there's something very strange going on.

Comment: try to send some valid attributes to check if it works for exemple :  socket.emit('hello', {id:user.id, name:user.name})

Comment: Oh, by the way, it's not actually caused by a client-side error, is it?

Comment: It works with valid attributes : socket.emit('hello', { firstname: user.firstname, lastname: user.lastname }). And I receive it client side (which does not produce any error).

Comment: OK ! and when you try to pass you whole object you get error server side or client side ?

Comment: I get the error client side, because the server resets the connection : WebSocket connection to 'ws://<IP>/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=5WuTpgno8_6tjtAAAA' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established. Actually, it is not event an error, but a warning from Chrome.

Comment: It turns out after some investigations that I can't emit my 'user' object if it contains more than 6 properties (out of 18)... Any idea ?

Comment: I found where the problem is !! I can't send accents (é, è, à...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer -_- !

Actually, it turned out I could not send accents (é, è, à...). And that is because my client side socket.io package was older than the server side one (1.7.? against 2.0.3).

I hope this answer will at least help the next person trying to emit an object with accents...

Answer (score 0):

you can only emit something that can be stringified via `JSON.stringify` ( -> no circular references). As you are trying to send down the whole mongooseDocument, that will fail.

Either you can do a `mongooseModel.find({...}).lean().exec(function callback(err, user){...})` which will return you a plain javascript object instead of the mongooseDocument (which can be serialized) or you can use the [mongoose.toJSON method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#toJSON) to convert it yourself.

regarding the problems of socket.io/angular, I can't help as you provided not enough code